# Is there an (interesting) mathematical theory in first order logic that is inconsistent with Peano Arithmetic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

There are first order theories that don't entail PA, like Tarski's elementary geometry.

Is there one that isn't consistent with PA, aka T + NON-PA would be sound? (Ideally it wouldn't be a "pathological" example)

Comment: I've added the "logic" tag. I've also removed the "arithmetic" tag - that tag is just for questions about basic arithmetic.

Comment: Some examples are $\Bbb{Q}$, $\Bbb{Z}[X]$, $\Bbb{Z}[X]/(p(x))$ for any polynomial $p$ that has no integral roots, any ring of non-zero characteristic $\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

There's always PA+$\neg$Con(PA), but that's a bit pathological. More seriously, the most obvious one to my mind is the theory of the field of real numbers, $Th(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$. Perhaps surprisingly, even though the reals are bigger, their theory is simpler - [Tarski showed that it's decidable!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_of_first-order_theories_of_the_real_numbers). The field of rationals, meanwhile, [is undecidable](https://mathoverflow.net/a/19852/28128) (although the complexity of its $\Sigma_1$ theory [is still unknown](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03239)).

There are other things to look at as well. For example, we could look at the theory of Boolean rings; this contains the sentence "$\forall x(x+x=0)$," so clearly contradicts PA. As a more complicated example, we could look at the theory of the field $(\mathbb{Q}; +,\times)$, or of the ring of "integer parts" of Puiseaux series; this contradicts PA, since even simple instances of the induction scheme fail. *(Interestingly, it **does** satisfy a weak version of induction, namely "open induction"; the study of the model theory of this structure is part of the general model theory of induction principles.)*

Comment: [Apparently not](https://mathoverflow.net/a/19852/28128).

Comment: @MikhailKatz Neat - it looks like I was thinking about the $\Sigma_1$ theory.

Comment: Boolean rings are rings that satisfy $x^2 = x$. $x + x = 0$ gives rings of characteristic $2$.

Comment: Elaborating on Rob Arthan's comment, every Boolean ring has characteristic 2 (think about $(x+x)^2$), but the converse is false.